# Fastq Concatenation

Tags: python, text-processing

I have generated contigs that have been put into a fastq format. I was wondering if anyone knows how I could grab the nucleotide sequence between two characters and generate one long contig? I am using Python 2.6.6. I have also added an example of what I want:

Current File Layout:

```
>DHWCT801:455:H5HHJBCXX:1:2109:10376:67348/1
GACTCCTCGCCCAACTACGACGGCCAGGAGCAGGAACCCGACGTCCTGCCCGCCGCCTACCCGAACCTGCTGGTCAACGGCTCGTCCGGGATCGCGGTCGG
>DHWCT801:455:H5HHJBCXX:2:1105:15915:79934/2
ACTCGGTGTAACGCATGGCGGCGGCACCGTCGTTGCCGCGGGAGCCGAAGTTACCCTGGCCCTGCACCATCGGGTAGCGCATGGCCCACGGCTGCGCGAGG
>DHWCT801:455:H5HHJBCXX:2:1114:17610:55148/2
AAGCGCTCCTACCTCGATTACGCCATGAGCGTGATCGTGTCCCGTGCGCTGCCGGATGCGCGCGACGGTTTGAAGCCGGTGCACCGGCGCATTTTG
```

What I want:

```
GACTCCTCGCCCAACTACGACGGCCAGGAGCAGGAACCCGACGTCCTGCCCGCCGCCTACCCGAACCTGCTGGTCAACGGCTCGTCCGGGATCGCGGTCGGACTCGGTGTAACGCATGGCGGCGGCACCGTCGTTGCCGCGGGAGCCGAAGTTACCCTGGCCCTGCACCATCGGGTAGCGCATGGCCCACGGCTGCGCGAGGAAGCGCTCCTACCTCGATTACGCCATGAGCGTGATCGTGTCCCGTGCGCTGCCGGATGCGCGCGACGGTTTGAAGCCGGTGCACCGGCGCATTTTG
```

P.S.:
I have multiple files so if there is a way to automate this by submitting it to my cluster and saving each individual file with the original name + concatenation added to the end I'd appreciate it. However I do believe I could figure that out.

Comment: Python 2.6? What's your Ubuntu release? If that's the default Python of your Ubuntu installation you should really upgrade because it's old and unsupported.

Comment: I'm using a cluster to perform my computations from schools. The cluster is maintained by the school and the software is updated by them... so unfortunately I am only able to use what they have, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

### With Grep

```sh
grep -ve '^>' source.fastaq
```

Result:

```
GACTCCTCGCCCAACTACGACGGCCAGGAGCAGGAACCCGACGTCCTGCCCGCCGCCTACCCGAACCTGCTGGTCAACGGCTCGTCCGGGATCGCGGTCGG
ACTCGGTGTAACGCATGGCGGCGGCACCGTCGTTGCCGCGGGAGCCGAAGTTACCCTGGCCCTGCACCATCGGGTAGCGCATGGCCCACGGCTGCGCGAGG
AAGCGCTCCTACCTCGATTACGCCATGAGCGTGATCGTGTCCCGTGCGCTGCCGGATGCGCGCGACGGTTTGAAGCCGGTGCACCGGCGCATTTTG
```

I believe that line breaks are ignored in FASTA and its variations. If you want to rid of them pipe the result through `tr -d '\n'`.

### With Python 2 and 3

This approach uses Python as a text processor. Depending on how you generate or read the FASTA data in your Python program there may be better approaches.

```python
import sys
sys.stdout.writelines(s for s in sys.stdin if not s.startswith('>'))
```

If you want it all on a single line alter the last line to:

```
[…]writelines(s.rstrip() for […])
```

Usage for both:

```sh
python select-contigs.py < source.fastaq
```

Comment: I am going to try this now. Thank you very much!